# Trying to model HIV using cellular automaton but can't replicate the results of some paper

Tags: python, modelling, cellular-automata

There is this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0008081.pdf) in which HIV is modelled using cellular automaton. I am trying to replicate this work but I am not getting the same results as the authors. In this paper the authors describe the rules they are implementing. I will post my implementation of the code after the rules description.

constants and other variables are here:

```Python
prob = .05 # probability of a cell being fuel, otherwise it's clear
total_time = 200 # simulation time
terrain_size = [100,100] # size of the simulation: 10000 cells

tau = 4 # time after update
R = 4 # num of infected A2 cells it takes for some healthy cell to become infected
pRepl =  .99 # chance of cell being reborn
pInfec = 10e-4 # chance of being born as infected

# states hold the state of each cell
states = np.zeros((total_time,*terrain_size))
# stores when a A1 cells becomes A2
taus = np.zeros(terrain_size)
# spawn some HIV cells
states[0] = np.random.choice([0,1],size=terrain_size,p=[1-prob,prob])
```

Rule 1: Update of a healthy cell: (a): if it has at least one infected-A1 neighbor, it becomes infected-A1. (b): if it has no infected-A1 neighbor but does have at least R (2 < R < 8) infected-A2 neighbors, it becomes infected- A1 (c): otherwise it stays healthy.

```Python
# Define the neighborhood
Neighborhood = states[t-1,max(x-1, 0):min(x+2, states[t-1].shape[0]), max(y-1, 0):min(y+2, states[t-1].shape[1])]

if states[t-1,x,y] == 0: # healthy cell
                
    # are there infected cells in neighbourhood
    infectedA1CellInNeighbourhood = 1 in Neighborhood
                
    # how many A2 cells in neighbourhood
    numInfectedA2 = np.count_nonzero(Neighborhood == 2)
                
    if infectedA1CellInNeighbourhood or numInfectedA2 >= R: # healthy cell has A1 in neighbourhood
        states[t,x,y] = 1 # cell becomes infected A1
        taus[x,y] = tau
```

Rule 2: An infected-A1 cell becomes infected-A2 after τ time steps.

```Python
if states[t-1,x,y] == 1: # A1 infected cell
                
    # after tau time steps, A1 will become A2
    if taus[x,y] == 0:
        states[t,x,y] = 2
    else:
        taus[x,y] -= 1
```

Rule 3: Infected-A2 cells become dead cells.

```Python
if states[t-1,x,y] == 2: # A2 infected cell

    # cells A2 die
    states[t,x,y] = 3
```

Rule 4: (a) Dead cells can be replaced by healthy cells with probability prepl in the next time step, (or remain
dead with probability 1 − p
cell introduced may be replaced by an infected-A1 with probability pinf ec .

```Python
if states[t-1,x,y] == 3:
    # cell is reborn either as healthy or infected

    born = (random.random() <= pRepl)
    infected = (random.random() <= pInfec)
    if born and infected:
        states[t,x,y] = 2
    elif born:
        states[t,x,y] = 0
```

plotting my results looks like this:

[image]

but it should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: I encourage you to [edit] your post to provide a proper reference for the paper (title, authors, and where published), so that others with the same question can find this page via search.  I also encourage you to state a specific question.  This is a question-and-answer site, so we require you to articulate a question -- don't make us guess.  Double-checking your implementation might be off-topic here, as we are not a coding site.

Comment: I see at least one simple bug: you're starting the born-infected cells in state A2 rather than A1. Fixing that _might_ be enough to get your results to match the paper.